# Getting null list with model on post MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have list inside the role model which is RoleCapability .I connected it in the fluent nhibernate . until Iposte the model to the controller I'm getting RoleCapability lists count is zero.

```
 public class Roles : IEntity
 {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }


#region Referacies

     public virtual IList<RoleCapabilities> RoleCapabilities { get; set; }

#endregion

    public Roles()
    {

         RoleCapabilities = new List<RoleCapabilities>();

    }
}
```

Below is the controller function

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Roles entity)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                if (entity.Id == 0)
                {


                    _RolesService.Insert(entity);
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                   _RolesService.Update(entity);
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error  " }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error " }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I've checked the result of the form in the javascript so the list is full with the data but after getting the model to the controller. It came empty the list of the RoleCapabilites

```
   @model MBA.Core.Entities.Roles
   @{
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list1 = ViewBag.CapabilityList1;
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = ViewBag.CapabilityList;

    }
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Roles", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" 
     }))
```

{

```
<div class="form-group">
    <table>
        <tr>


 <td>
          @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Capabilities, list1, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display:block", @id = 
         "sourceItems" })

        </td>
            <td><input id="ShiftRight" type="button" value=">>" /></td>
            <td><input id="ShiftLeft" type="button" value="<<" /></td>
            <td>
                   @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.RoleCapabilities, list, new { @class =  
           "form-control", @style = "display:block", @id = "destinationItems" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn" />
     </div>

       }
```

here is the javascript code

```
  function SubmitForm(form) {
    debugger;

    if ($(form).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: form.method,
            url: form.action,
            //"datatype": "json"
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the variable formData in your JS function? (data: formData)

Comment: To view the data in the model of method AddOrEdit(), you can put a breakpoint inside the AddOrEdit() method. To view what is inside the posted back form-data in Ajax call, you can open the browser's developer's tools and check the posted back data.

Comment: Yeah in the ajax I've check the form and it has the data inside the RoleCapabilities list. But in the controller its coming null ??